# Solving n! with C (equation error somewhere)

Tags: c, math, equation

In my quest to learn C I've come across a task which is causing me a few problems. I need to make an equation for the approximate value of the formulae n!, which can be described as:

n! = n^n*e^(-n)*sqrt(2(2*n+1/3)*PI), however I simply cannot get my values to corrospond with the actual value. 5! = 120ish

I can get a value of some 148ish

Can't figure out where my code is wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14156
#define E_CONST 2.7828

int main ()
{

double num;
double calc, first, second, third, fourth;

printf("Give an int: ");
scanf("%lf", &num);


first = pow(num , num);

second = pow(E_CONST, -num);

third = (2 * num + 1/3);

fourth = sqrt(2*third*PI);

//calc = first * second * fourth;

calc = pow(num, num) * pow(E_CONST, -num) * sqrt(2*(2*num+(1/3))*PI);
printf("Input: %f", num);

printf("1: %.2f\n2: %.10f\n3: %.8f\n4: %.2f\n", first, second, third, fourth);

printf("\nInt was: %.2f\n\nApproximate number: %.5f", num, calc);

return 0;
}
```

Feel like i have tried everything. The code is a bit messy, but it's because I've scrambled so much with it now.

Comment: Does third equal (2 * (num + 1/3)) or ((2 * num) + 1/3)?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe `1/3` is evaluated to `0` (integer division)

Comment: I'd definitely say that line is where the error is - it's ambiguous and wrong...  depending on the right precedence you probably want:
third = ((2 * num) + ((float)1/(float)3))
or
third = (2 * (num + ((float)1/(float)3)))

Comment: @Matt: why `(float)`? I think it's better to use `double`, almost always. Also `3.14` is a `double` :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`3.14156` is a bad value for `PI`: it's better to use `3.1416`, or `3.14159`, or `4 * atan(1)`, or, for POSIX implementations, `M_PI`.

`2.7828` is a **very bad** value for `e`: it's better to use `2.7183`, or `exp(1)`, or, for POSIX implementations, `M_E`.

`1/3` is integer division, the result is 0: it's better to use `1.0/3`.

Also your approximation is incorrect. The [correct approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html) is

```
n^n * e^(-n) * sqrt((2*n+1/3)*PI)
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much. Will make an effort to try and remember the .0 for doubles. It was in fact the equation that was wrong (Along with my mistype of e), but that was in fact due to the equation written in the book I'm using.

Comment: Why not simply use the `M_PI` macro from `math.h` ?

Comment: @DarkDust: `M_PI` is not required by the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). *It is required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/math.h.html) though.*

Comment: +1 for checking the value of `e`. I would consider it not only very bad but wrong, with the `1` missing.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you fell into the integer division trap with `1/3`, which has the value `0`.  You need to write this with floating point constants as `1.0 / 3.0`.

Comment: We have this about once a week, so there will be plenty of more opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to type `1.0/3.0` to get one third.